# Early call to javascript function on IE page load

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, onload

I'm using some checkboxes in my HTML. When the page is load, I want to do some operations depending on which boxes are checked. The problem is that IE is calling my onLoad function before it sets the value of the boxes. (Works fine in FF of course)

Code:

```
<script language='JavaScript' type = "text/javascript">

    window.onload = new function() {
        alert("wat");
    }

</script>
```

Debugging, I see that the boxes are not yet checked when I'm getting the alert, but after dismissing it, they are chekced as should.

How can I make my javascript code execute after the load is done?

Comment: Checkboxes are already checked in markup?

Comment: Some are, it depends on user's input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this `new` keyword confuses IE `window.onload` event. Remove `new` keyword before handler function:

```
<script language='JavaScript' type = "text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        alert("wat");
    }

</script>
```